# Computing the Free Parafermion Spectrum

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry, clifford-algebra, integrable-systems, strong-correlated

In Fendley's paper on Free Parafermion (https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6049), Fendley used some operator techniques to show that $$Q_{2 L}\left(\epsilon_k^n\right)=0$$ which is the formal derivation of Baxter's argument in this paper:

> Baxter R J 1989 A simple solvable ZN Hamiltonian Phys. Lett. A 140 155-157 https://doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(89)90884-0

Here is the section in Fendley's paper that I am referring to:

> The eigenvalues can be easily found by noting that because of the grading, the matrix $\left(\mathcal{M}_n\right)^n$ breaks into $n$ blocks of size $L \times L$. Namely, by the definition (84), $\mathcal{H} \eta^{(s n+q)}$ always gives some combination of operators $\eta^{\left(s^{\prime} n+q+1\right)}$. Thus $\mathcal{H}^n$ mixes only $\eta^{\left(s^{\prime} n+q\right)}$ with the same value of $q$. Then the resulting blocks $\mathcal{B}_q$ are independent of $n$, and are
> $$
> \left(\mathcal{B}_0\right)_{a a^{\prime}}=\left(\mathcal{M}^2\right)_{2 a-1,2 a^{\prime}-1}, \quad\left(\mathcal{B}_l\right)_{a a^{\prime}}=\left(\mathcal{M}^2\right)_{2 a, 2 a^{\prime}} .
> $$
> with $l=1, \ldots n-1$. Thus no more work is necessary to find the eigenvalues - the values $\epsilon_k^n$ for general $n$ are indeed the same as the $\epsilon_k^2$ in the free-fermion case! This confirms Baxter's result
> $$
> Q_{2 L}\left(\epsilon_k^n\right)= det(\mathcal{F}-\epsilon_k^n I) = 0 .
> $$

where
$$\mathcal{F} = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & t_1^{n / 2} & 0 & \cdots & \\
t_1^{n / 2} & 0 & t_2^{n / 2} & & \\
0 & t_2^{n / 2} & 0 & & \\
\vdots & & & & t_{2 L-1}^{n / 2} \\
& & & t_{2 L-1}^{n / 2} & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
and its rescaled version is
$$\mathcal{M}_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & \gamma_1 & 0 & \cdots & & \\
1 & 0 & \gamma_2 & & & \\
0 & 1 & 0 & & & \\
\vdots & & & & 0 & \gamma_{2 L-1} \\
& & & & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
I tried to reconstruct $\mathcal{M}_3$ for $L=4$, which is a $12 \times 12$ matrix:
$$\mathcal{M} = \left(\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
0 & 0 & \gamma 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 2& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
I don't understand Fendley's argument here, especially $(\mathcal{M}_3)^3$ does not break down into three $4\times 4$ matrices. Moreover, $\mathcal{M}_2$ here is a $8\times 8$ matrix when $L=4$. I don't know why $
\epsilon_k^n=\epsilon_k^2(\text { Ising })
$

Can someone help me to understand the material here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal{M}_3$ indeed breaks down into three $4\times 4$ matrices, but relabeling different columns are needed. Each block matrices $B_i (i = {0,1,2})$ can also be computed from the elements of $\mathcal{F}= \mathcal{M}_2$. In other words:
$$
\mathcal{M}_3^3 =  \left(\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
\gamma 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 1 \gamma 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \gamma 1+\gamma 2 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 2 \gamma 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \gamma 1+\gamma 2 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 2 \gamma 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 2+\gamma 3 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 3 \gamma 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 3+\gamma 4 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 4 \gamma 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 3+\gamma 4 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 4 \gamma 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 4+\gamma 5 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 5 \gamma 6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 5+\gamma 6 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 6 \gamma 7 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 5+\gamma 6 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 6 \gamma 7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 6+\gamma 7 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 7 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma 7
\end{array}\right)
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{M}_2^2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\gamma 1 & 0 & \gamma 1 \gamma 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \gamma 1+\gamma 2 & 0 & \gamma 2 \gamma 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & \gamma 2+\gamma 3 & 0 & \gamma 3 \gamma 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma 3+\gamma 4 & 0 & \gamma 4 \gamma 5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma 4+\gamma 5 & 0 & \gamma 5 \gamma 6 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma 5+\gamma 6 & 0 & \gamma 6 \gamma 7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma 6+\gamma 7 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma 7
\end{array}\right)
$$
have the same eigenvalues but with different multiplicity because these 2 matrices have different dimensions.

To conclude, we can use the same multinomial $$
Q_{2 L}\left(\epsilon_k^n\right)=\operatorname{det}\left(\mathcal{F}-\epsilon_k^n I\right)=0
$$ to compute the spectrum of all $\mathbb{Z}_n$ symmetry parafermion.